# How to center image inside a circular imageview?

Tags: android, image, imageview

I have an ImageView. I have done some manipulation to make it circular. All is good. But, I realize that the image is not centered. Apparently, the image is positioned from the top left of the ImageView. How can I make this image centered to the circular ImageView?

Here is my code:

```
// Decode the Byte[] into bitmap
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
// Set the Bitmap into the imageView
mImage.setImageBitmap(bmp);

//circle img
int wbmp = bmp.getWidth();
int hbmp = bmp.getHeight();
int diameter;
if (wbmp > hbmp) {
   diameter = hbmp;
} else {
   diameter = wbmp;
}

Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, wbmp, hbmp, true);
Bitmap conv_bm = ImageHelper.getRoundedRectBitmap(resized, diameter);

mImage.setImageBitmap(conv_bm);
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
//circle img ends
```

and this is the ImageHelper:

```
public class ImageHelper {

//circle image
public static Bitmap getRoundedRectBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int radius) {
    Bitmap result = null;
    try {

        Bitmap sbitmap;
        if(bitmap.getWidth() != radius || bitmap.getHeight() != radius) sbitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, radius, radius,false);
        else sbitmap = bitmap;

        result = Bitmap.createBitmap(sbitmap.getWidth(), sbitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);

        int color = 0xff424242;
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, sbitmap.getWidth(), sbitmap.getHeight());

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(color);
        canvas.drawCircle(sbitmap.getWidth() / 2, sbitmap.getHeight() / 2,
                sbitmap.getWidth() / 2, paint);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError o) {
    }
    return result;
}
//circle image ends
```

}

Comment: Did you set any `android:scaleType` in the xml file you add your circular image view? You can try setting it to `fitCenter`

Comment: yes I did. it is set to centerCrop. and I believe, because I did some modification in java, the scaleType from xml doesn't work. at least thats what the others have been saying